# I made a test package and published it on npm but I can't import and use it

Tags: reactjs, npm

I made a test package with create-react-app and published it on npm but I can't import and use it  in my project that I created with create-react-app and it says
Module not found: Can't resolve 'myfirst-pkg-soheil-dev'  my package is this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/myfirst-pkg-soheil-dev
appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must publish the build code of your package on npm. By a JavaScript point of view your package is empty if you import from root.

Looking at your source code:

- you don't specify the [main](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) entry point in package.json
- there's no dist/build directory with your code

Alternatively you can put your index.js or index.es.js in your root but as it seems you are using create-react-app, so you must simply [build](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build).

Or you can `import aaa from 'myfirst-pkg-soheil-dev/src'` but this is not the way to go.

Final note:

- publishing test packages on npm is not a good idea
- create-react-app is not for providing *libraries* (that should go on npm) but final applications. Take a look at [create-react-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library) instead.

Comment: create-react-app doesn't handle the main entry? because I used npm run build before publishing

Comment: @mssoheil seems not, but it's uncommon to publish on npm stuff created with create-react-app. A react app is (commonly) something you deploy on your host/page/site... there's no value to have an app on npm.